# Dashboard for a team

Tags: sonarqube

We are using Developer Cockpit in our company. It's great, but what would be awesome is a dashboard for a group of developers, for example single team. Is there a way to create such dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the purpose of the following ticket: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VIEWS-121 ("Make the Views plugin support the Developer Cockpit plugin by allowing to create some views on developer").